# Unable to send messages from Spring boot (Producer) app in AWS Fargate to AWS MSK

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I have a spring boot application which produces messages to `Kafka (AWS MSK)`. From my local machine I am able to send messages to `MSK` where as the same application is unable to send messages from `AWS Fargate`.

```
Logs:
Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(id = null, nodes = [<bootstrap server> (id: -1 rack: null), <bootstrap server> (id: -2 rack: null),<bootstrap server> (id: -3 rack: null)], partitions = [], controller = null)
Initialize connection to node <bootstrap server> (id: -2 rack: null) for sending metadata request
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```